# Make a Button do something, depending on which CheckBox is checked

Tags: java, android

I've written this code, please, tell me what should I do to make the Button do something depending on which CheckBox is checked.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_costi_di_impianto);
}

public void CalcolaC(View view) {

    double Onorario1,SpeseD1,CostI1,Iva1,Deb1,Rit1,ccp1,Netto1;
    //
    Onorario1 = 0;
    SpeseD1 = 0;
    ccp1 = 0;

    //
    EditText Onorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Onorario);
    EditText SpeseD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpeseD);
    TextView CostI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CostI);
    TextView Iva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Iva);
    TextView Deb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Deb);
    TextView Rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rit);
    TextView ccp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
    TextView Netto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Netto);
    final CheckBox checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    final CheckBox checkBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    //
    try{
        Onorario1 = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(Onorario.getText().toString())*100.0)/100.0;
        SpeseD1 = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(SpeseD.getText().toString())*100.0)/100.0;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        ErrorMsg();
        Pulisci(view);
        return;
    }

    if(checkBox1.isChecked())
                ccp1 = Onorario1 * 2 / 100;
                Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                //
                ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));
    if(checkBox2.isChecked())
                ccp1 = Onorario1 * 4 / 100;
                Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                //
                ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));

    }

private void Pulisci(View view) {
    EditText Onorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Onorario);
    EditText SpeseD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpeseD);
    TextView CostI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CostI);
    TextView Iva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Iva);
    TextView Deb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Deb);
    TextView Rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rit);
    TextView ccp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
    TextView Netto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Netto);
    Onorario.setText("");
    SpeseD.setText("");
    CostI.setText("");
    Iva.setText("");
    Deb.setText("");
    Rit.setText("");
    ccp.setText("");
    Netto.setText("");

}

private void ErrorMsg() {
    AlertDialog Msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    Msg.setTitle("Errore");
    Msg.setMessage("Hai inserito dei dati non validi!");
    Msg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }});
    Msg.show();
}
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}

}
```

Here is the logCat

```
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCheckboxClicked(View) in the activity class com.ITE.economiaaziendale.CostiDiImpianto for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'checkBox2'
```

Comment: use oncheckedchangelistener ...\

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: Implement the interface then override the method to listen for checkbox changes and then inside that method, do whatever you want to the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listener, like that:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){

            } else {

            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

set **`setOnClickListener()`** to your checkboxs.

```
checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {             
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                     ccp1 = Onorario1 * 2 / 100;
                    Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                    Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                    CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                    Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                    Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                    //
                    ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                    Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                    Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                    CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                    Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                    Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));       
        }
      }
    });

checkBox2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {             
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {           
               ccp1 = Onorario1 * 4 / 100;
                Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                //
                ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));
        }
      }
    });
```

or **`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`**.

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
            ccp1 = Onorario1 * 2 / 100;
                Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                //
                ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));       
        }
});

checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                ccp1 = Onorario1 * 4 / 100;
                Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                //
                ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));
        }
});
```

Comment: Now when i press the checkbox it do the calcs, and the button cause an exception

Comment: use setOnCheckedChangeListener(), wath exception give me more details?

Comment: With setOnCheckedChangeListener() it gives that
02-11 19:17:45.071: E/AndroidRuntime(488): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method OnClickListener(View) in the activity class com.ITE.economiaaziendale.CostiDiImpianto for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'checkBox2'

Comment: And with setOnclickListener gives 02-11 20:18:27.106: E/AndroidRuntime(484): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Calc1(View) in the activity class com.ITE.economiaaziendale.CostiDiImpianto for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'CalcolaC'

Answer (score 0):

First of all define all views globally and implement your onCheckedChangedListener in your activity class i.e:

```
Edittext Onorario, SpeseD;
TextView CostI, Iva, Deb, Rit, ccp, Netto; 
CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2;   
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements onCheckedChangedListener {
```

Then do the initialization process in your onCreate method i.e:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_costi_di_impianto);

Onorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Onorario);
SpeseD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpeseD);
CostI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CostI);
Iva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Iva);
Deb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Deb);
Rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rit);
ccp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
Netto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Netto);
checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
//Here add your onCheckedChangedListener to each checkbox
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);   
}
```

Now on your setOnCheckedChangeListener do what you like i.e

```
   @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

switch (buttonView.getId()){

case R.id.checkBox1:
    if(isChecked){
    //Do here all your button click stuff or set text to any edittext or textview if the first ckeckbox is checked..

    }else{
     //do something if the checkbox1 is not checked
    }
    break;
case R.id.checkBox2:
    if(isChecked){
    //do here what you want to do when checkbox2 is checked 
    }else{
    //and here when the checkbox2 is not checked
    }
    break;
}
```

here all answers are correct but your problem is in writing standard.
As i saw in your code your onCreate method is aware of all stuff. So do all processes in a good manner which will help you to findout compile and runtime errors.